# Main reason of using "^"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I don't understand what  what the purpose of using "^" in the second code?
Another problem is that I don't retrieve right information in second code compare to the first code. Why?

```
-- First code, use adventurework DW 2008
select FirstName, LastName from DimCustomer
where LastName like '[j-N]%'
order by LastName

-- Second code, use adventurework DW 2008
select FirstName, LastName from DimCustomer
where LastName like '[^L-N]%'
order by LastName
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`^` means where the character is **not** within the specified range.

Which will probably explain why you don't get the results you though you would?